# headers_sent() seems not working?

Tags: php

**Important Note** : `output_buffering` is off and I have checked it by `get_ini()` so please do not answer iteratives.

I have a simple php code:

```
<?php
```

in first step I will send a header, I also have write nothing before my php start tag and header is first:

```
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

now i want to be sure that my header has been sent so i use header_sent() function

```
if(!headers_sent()) {
    ?><script type="text/javascript">alert('No headers have been sent')</script><?php
} else {
    ?><script type="text/javascript">alert('headers have been sent')</script><?php
}
?>
```

Unfortunately I don't know why I will encountered with "No headers have been sent" while I expect headers have been sent.

Answer (score 2):

Headers are send to the web server the first time you try to output body data. Once that has happened, you cannot send any more headers. A more appropriate name for `headers_sent` might be `do_i_still_have_the_chance_to_send_any_more_headers_now()`. If `headers_sent` is `false`, you can still send more headers with `header()`; if it's `true` you cannot send any more headers. If `headers_sent` is `false`, that does not mean that no headers *will* be sent nor that your previous `header` call was ignored.

If you want to check what headers *will* be send (or have already been), see [`headers_list`](http://php.net/headers_list).